# Undefined method error for << in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I'm learning Ruby with [The Fundamentals of Ruby](http://courses.tutsplus.com/courses/the-fundamentals-of-ruby) course, by José Mota, and while following the course I got these errors, I'm not sure what happened. The code is exactly the same as the video in the course whose Ruby version is 1.9.3 but I have Ruby 2.0.

Here is the code:

`blog.rb`:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require_relative "Tweetable"

module Blog

class Post

    include Tweetable
    attr_reader :author, :title, :body, :comments

    def initialize options
        @author = options[:author]
        @title  = options[:title]
        @body   = options[:body]
        @comments = options[:comments]  || []   
    end

    def insert_comment *comments
        comments.each { |c| @comments << c }
    end

    def insert_random_comment 
        @comments << Comment.new(user:"Kshitiz Rimal", body:"Thik chha keta")
    end



end

class Comment
    include Tweetable
    attr_reader :user, :body

    def initialize options
        @user   = options[:user]
        @body   = options[:body]
    end

end

end
```

When I try to load the module from another file, with the code as:

`module.rb`:

```
require_relative "blog"

post = Blog::Post.new author: "Kshitiz Rimal",
                  title:  "Hello new Post",
                  body:   "This is a new body",
                  comments: Blog::Comment.new(user: "Random Name",     body: "Good one")

post.insert_random_comment
```

I'm trying to insert a random comment into the post. I got following error:

```
 Users/kshitizrimal/blog.rb:23:in `insert_random_comment': undefined method `<<' for #<Blog::Comment:0x007fd9b995ee40> (NoMethodError)
from modules.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you `module.rb` should be:

```
require_relative "blog"

post = Blog::Post.new author: "Kshitiz Rimal",
                  title:  "Hello new Post",
                  body:   "This is a new body",
                  comments: [Blog::Comment.new(user: "Random Name",     body: "Good one")]

post.insert_random_comment
```

This will set `@comments` as a list, which supports the `<<` operator...

Comment: thankyou.. so what happened was that, i needed to add the comment as array entry??

Comment: exactly. `comments` hints that this is a _collection_ of comments, so it should be an array.

Answer (score 4):

`@comments = options[:comments]  || []` assigned to `@comments` a `Blog::Comment` object. But the class `Blog::Comment` has no instance method `#<<` defined in it.

Now inside the method `insert_random_comment` below line causes the error -

```
@comments << Comment.new(user:"Kshitiz Rimal", body:"Thik chha keta")
```

The above lime means

```
@comments.<<(Comment.new(user:"Kshitiz Rimal", body:"Thik chha keta"))
```

While you have insatiate the class `Blog::Post` class, you passed the below :-

```
comments: Blog::Comment.new(user: "Random Name", ...
```

That's why

```
 @comments = options[:comments]  || []
```

actually assigned to the object of `Blog::Comment`, not the `Array`. `Array#<<` method exist, but in your case, `#<<` is not called on the `Array` instance.

You include `Tweetable`, but the error also confirms that the module didn't add any method `#<<` to your class `Blog::Comment`, as the module itself also don't have the method `#<<` defined into it.

Comment: how can i insert random comment then?

Comment: @monk Uri did it before me. I went to my Boss's desk. That supposed to be my *next edit*.